# Can't lock variable with QMutex

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside2

I am new at multithreading. I have a PySide2 app. It has 3 different threads. The first one is the main thread that runs the GUI, the latter is responsible for the camera stream, and the third one responsible for the Flask that provides an API to access GUI from other points. (According to the article accessing GUI from different threads is not a good idea: https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/#reusing-threads-qrunnable-and-qthreadpool).

When a request came to the endpoint I want to get some values on the GUI and return them. I tried to implement the signal and slot mechanism to carry it out. However, my endpoint returns the default value of the variable before I get it from GUI. The thread that responsible for the endpoint is not waiting for the GUI thread to set the value that will be returned. I tried to lock variables with QMutex in different ways to set the value by GUI firstly yet I couldn't be successful. How can I lock the variable and return after setting the value?

The Flask class which runs on the thread:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QObject, Slot, QMutex
from flask import Flask

from SharedData import SharedData

class API(QObject):
    signal_get_value = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(API, self).__init__()
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.app.add_url_rule('/get_value/', 'get_value', self.get_value)
        self.data = SharedData()


    def start(self):
        self.app.run()

    def get_value(self):
        self.signal_get_value.emit()
        measurement = self.data.get_measurement()
        data = {"measurement": measurement}

        return data
```

The SharedData class:

```
class SharedData:
    __measurement = None

    @classmethod
    def get_measurement(cls):
        return cls.__measurement

    @classmethod
    def set_measurement(cls, measurement):
        cls.__measurement = measurement
```

The method that changes the value in my GUI module:

```
mutex = QMutex()

    def read_measurement(self):
        self.mutex.lock()
        
        #some processes and the output assign to the 'result' variable
        
        self.api.data.set_measurement(result)
        self.mutex.unlock()
```

**EDIT**

I am adding a code to clarify it. You can find the `read_measurement` method in it. The rest of the code same. @eyllanesc

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, QMutex
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QLabel

from API import API

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.init_UI()


    def init_UI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(690, 530)
        self.image_lbl = QLabel()

        self.image_lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap("img/im.jpg"))

        btn_cnt = QPushButton("Continue")
        btn_pa = QPushButton("Pause")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(btn_cnt)
        hbox.addWidget(btn_pa)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.image_lbl)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.start_api()
        self.show()


    def start_api(self):
        self.thread_API = QThread()
        self.api = API()
        self.api.moveToThread(self.thread_API)
        self.thread_API.started.connect(self.api.start)
        self.api.signal_get_value.connect(self.read_measurement)

        self.thread_API.start()

    dv = 0
    mutex = QMutex()

    def read_measurement(self):
        self.mutex.lock()

        measurement = None
        result = "measurement " + str(self.dv)
        self.dv += 1
        self.api.data.set_measurement(result)

        self.mutex.unlock()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_form = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I added the example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way around the problem is that pause the API(worker) thread. I still wonder could I use mutex, semaphore or etc.

Added sleep method to pause the thread.

```
from time import sleep

from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QObject, Slot, QMutex
from flask import Flask

from SharedData import SharedData

class API(QObject):
    signal_get_value = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(API, self).__init__()
        self.__app = Flask(__name__)
        self.__app.add_url_rule('/get_value/', 'get_value', self.get_value)
        self.data = SharedData()
        self.pause = True


    def start(self):
        self.__app.run()

    def __sleep_thread(self):
        """method pauses the thread to enable other threads to get the request done 

        Returns
        -------
        None
        """

        while self.pause:
            sleep(0.05)

        self.pause = True


    def get_value(self):
        self.signal_get_value.emit()
        self.__sleep_thread()

        measurement = self.data.get_measurement()
        data = {"measurement": measurement}

        return data
```

GUI module.

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, QMutex
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QLabel

from API import API

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.init_UI()


    def init_UI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(690, 530)
        self.image_lbl = QLabel()

        self.image_lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap("img/im.jpg"))

        btn_cnt = QPushButton("Continue")
        btn_pa = QPushButton("Pause")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(btn_cnt)
        hbox.addWidget(btn_pa)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.image_lbl)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.start_api()
        self.show()


    def start_api(self):
        self.thread_API = QThread()
        self.api = API()
        self.api.moveToThread(self.thread_API)
        self.thread_API.started.connect(self.api.start)
        self.api.signal_get_value.connect(self.read_measurement)

        self.thread_API.start()
        # ToDo: Do I need the terminate thread when exited from the app?

    dv = 0
    def read_measurement(self):
        measurement = None
        result = "measurement " + str(self.dv)
        self.dv += 1
        self.api.data.set_measurement(result)
        self.api.pause = False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_form = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```